# Delete empty row in XML File

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, delete-row

When creating an XML file, it always creates blank lines for me.
This code looks like this:

```
for row in tbody.find_elements_by_xpath('./tr'):
    itemsEmployee = row.find_elements_by_xpath('./td')
    fileWriter.writerow([itemsEmployee[1].text, itemsEmployee[5].text, itemsEmployee[2].text, itemsEmployee[3].text,
                         itemsEmployee[4].text, itemsEmployee[6].text, itemsEmployee[7].text, itemsEmployee[8].text])
```

First of all, I don't know why I get blank lines. But anyway.

I now want to delete the empty lines and save the XML. (In a new file)

My attempt was as follows:

```
def deleteEmptyRowsInXML():
    input = open('../data/employees_csv.csv', 'rb')
    output = open('../data/employees.csv', 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for row in csv.reader(input):
        if row:
            writer.writerow(row)
    input.close()
    os.remove('../data/employees_csv.csv')
    output.close()
```

I would also like a solution in the same file.

Get the error:

```
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

in this line:

```
for row in csv.reader(input):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A csv writer expects its underlying file to be opened with `newline=''`. The rationale is that RFC 4180 mandates that a csv file should have `'\r\n'` as end of line independently on which system it is generated. So the `csv` module explicitely adds the `\r\n`, but if you forgot `newline=''` you get an empty line for each row.

So it should be: `output = open('../data/employees.csv', 'w', newline='')`

Comment: Thank your for that information. This was the solution. I do not need my function 'deleteEmptyRowsInXML' now.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the file was probably not opened in text mode.

And in fact you opened it in binary mode : "rb" means "read file in binary mode". And "wb" means "write file in binary mode"

So change to this:

```
input = open('../data/employees_csv.csv', 'r')
output = open('../data/employees.csv', 'w')
```

But that's possible that you'll have other errors too. For the moment, I can't say more cause we don't have a reproducible example. but it will perhaps be enough to change the lines I pointed.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I do not get an error now, but the empty lines are still there. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example? And you talk about an xml file, but your code loads a csv file: could you please clarify this? And I think that @Serge Ballesta answer will solves the other issue.

Comment: The solution was given by Serge Ballesta. But thanks for your input and the solution to my delete function.

Comment: Excellent! In addition of accepting his answer, you can +1 it too (it means that his answer is useful). Have a good day!